# parse html textfield to javascript

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, youtube

Hello I have a question and I've been googling it before asking to you guys and I can't find the solution. I would like to have the `data-id="video"` added in a textbox so that I can change it without changing the source file everytime.

```
<div class="youtube-container"><div class="youtube-player" data-id="VIDEO"></div></div>
```

Is it possible that I can change the "VIDEO" with a textfield??

I have a javascript that loads the video so that I can just type in a video id.

Hope someone can help me with this.

Below is the code that calls for the video id.

```
(function() {
var v = document.getElementsByClassName("youtube-player");
for (var n = 0; n < v.length; n++) {
    var p = document.createElement("div");
    p.innerHTML = labnolThumb(v[n].dataset.id);
    p.onclick = labnolIframe;
    v[n].appendChild(p);
}
```

I forgot to post this the first time.

Comment: Note: [tag:java] is not the same as [tag:javascript]. They are two different languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For parse:

```
$(".youtube-player").data("id")
```

For change content:

```
$(".youtube-player").data("id","NEW CONTENT")
```

how are you want to change it - on your choice, with select or textfield

You must add input

```
<input type="text">
```

And this jQuery code

```
$('input').on('change', function() {
        $('.youtube-player').data('id', $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: yes i would like to change it with a textfield could you show me an example?

Comment: I really apreciate your help, but I can not get it working. I have no idea of where I need to put your example in my script. I've tried what you explained but it does not work. Are you willing to show me how i must use it together? Anyway thanks for your help and quick answers..

Comment: you must connect jQuery library to your project first of all https://jquery.com/download/, and you can check example on this link   http://jsfiddle.net/ti_to/4c7kppe6/1/

Comment: Thanks I did exactly what you told me, I also understand that the example your giving where the alert is, I need to put my script but when I add the Video ID it does load the video only it doesn't work because it still loads the "VIDEO" by default and not the Video ID i put in there.